# No route matches [POST] "/session.account"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Hey I am facing problem that apears when I am trying to log in using Devise and Simple_Form 
after `http://localhost:3000/account/sign_in` it redirects me to `http://localhost:3000/session.account`where pop up error: No route matches [POST] "/session.account". 
 Any idea why? And how to get it back working?

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'tasks/completed', to: 'tasks#completed'
  get 'tasks/pending', to: 'tasks#pending'

  namespace :settings do
  resources :tags
  resources :categories
  end
  resources :settings
  resources :tasks

  devise_for :account

  devise_scope :account do
    get 'removal', to: 'devise/registrations#cancel'
  end

  devise_scope :user do
    delete 'session', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy'
  end

  root to: 'dashboards#index'
end
```

rake routes

```
                              removal GET    /removal(.:format)                                                                       devise/registrations#cancel
                              session DELETE /session(.:format)                                                                       devise/sessions#destroy
                  new_account_session GET    /account/sign_in(.:format)                                                               devise/sessions#new
                      account_session POST   /account/sign_in(.:format)                                                               devise/sessions#create
              destroy_account_session DELETE /account/sign_out(.:format)                                                              devise/sessions#destroy
                 new_account_password GET    /account/password/new(.:format)                                                          devise/passwords#new
                edit_account_password GET    /account/password/edit(.:format)                                                         devise/passwords#edit
                     account_password PATCH  /account/password(.:format)                                                              devise/passwords#update
                                      PUT    /account/password(.:format)                                                              devise/passwords#update
                                      POST   /account/password(.:format)                                                              devise/passwords#create
          cancel_account_registration GET    /account/cancel(.:format)                                                                devise/registrations#cancel
             new_account_registration GET    /account/sign_up(.:format)                                                               devise/registrations#new
            edit_account_registration GET    /account/edit(.:format)                                                                  devise/registrations#edit
                 account_registration PATCH  /account(.:format)                                                                       devise/registrations#update
                                      PUT    /account(.:format)                                                                       devise/registrations#update
                                      DELETE /account(.:format)                                                                       devise/registrations#destroy
                                      POST   /account(.:format)                                                                       devise/registrations#create   root GET    /
```

views/devise/session/new

```
<h2>Log in</h2>

<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :email,
                required: false,
                autofocus: true,
                input_html: { autocomplete: "email" } %>
    <%= f.input :password,
                required: false,
                input_html: { autocomplete: "current-password" } %>
    <%= f.input :remember_me, as: :boolean if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Log in" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Comment: You don't have a `sessions/account` route. You've only got an `account/sign_in` route as stated in the rake routes. 
Try `simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: account_session_path(resource_name))`

EDIT: the reason it's generating `/session.account` is because of the way you've used the helper. `session_path` is the top level, and you're handing it a resource, `account`

Comment: After changing path i am still getting redirected to `http://localhost:3000/account/sign_in.account` it throw another error : `ActionController::UnknownFormat in Devise::SessionsController#new (options.delete(:responder) || self.class.responder).call(self, resources, options) else raise ActionController::UnknownFormat end end`

Answer (score 0):

using session_path will match route to delete action , which accept 'DELETE' method, what you need here is sign_in path so you should use

```
account_session_path
```

which points to the sign_in path

Comment: After changing path i am still getting redirected to `http://localhost:3000/account/sign_in.account` it throw another error : `ActionController::UnknownFormat in Devise::SessionsController#new (options.delete(:responder) || self.class.responder).call(self, resources, options) else raise ActionController::UnknownFormat end end`

Answer (score 0):

OK problem solved in `url: session_path(resource_name))` i change to `url: new_session_path(resource_name))`and all is working as it should.